# Convertir un bitmap a string

Tags: java, android

¿Hay alguna forma de convertir un `bitmap` a `string` sin convertirlo a `base64`?.
Tengo una app que envía imágenes a una base de datos, pero las envío en `base64`, y esto ocupa mucha memoria (con base en lo que he leído) por esa razón necesito convertir el `bitmap` a `string`. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a convertir un `bitmap` a una `string` para guardar en una base de datos local?

Comment: sí, a eso me refiero.

Comment: No creo que sea posible y si lo es sin duda debe ser una mala práctica, la mejor práctica para "guardar" imágenes en bases de datos es guardando las imágenes en una carpeta específica, obteniendo su ruta absoluta _/path/to/image.jpg_ y guardarla en la base de datos

Comment: Sí lo sé pero me lo están pidiendo así.

Comment: Yo ya guardo las imágenes en la base de datos, las almaceno en base64, las mando por Json, necesito la forma de no enviarlas en base 64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque no realizar la conversión a String mediante encoding Base64,  la razón principal es que conservarías integridad de datos al convertir nuevamente a Bitmap.

> Tengo una app que envía imágenes a una base de datos...

Porque no guardas el path de la imagen considero más practico que guardar la imagen codificada en un registro de la base de datos.

---

Para convertir una Imagen (`bitmap`) a `String`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
mybitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] imagen = stream.toByteArray(); 
String imagenString = Base64.encode(imagen, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Si no deseas codificar (no recomendado lo ideal debe ser usando enconding Base64), simplemente:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
 mybitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
 byte[] imagen = stream.toByteArray();
 String imagenString = new String(imagen);
```

Comment: Sé que es más practico guardarlo en path, solo que me lo están pidiendo así, que guarde las imágenes en la base de datos (eso ya lo hago), solo que quería saber si había alguna forma de convertir un bitmap en string

Comment: Agregué respuesta, lo que deseas que es evitar la codificación base64, es la segunda opción. @jaroncascantePérez